# How to get Data from Database using ID from JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a JSON file from my device and it send a ID
and i want to deserialize the JSON file and use the ID as a parameter to select data to my database? please help me..

Comment: Sorry, start over. This question is a complete mess.

Comment: do you have id's only in the file as a json string ? or do you have ids plus some other stuff as well ?

Comment: yes, only the id is in the json .. iwant to deserialize it and use to getalldataByID and return it to the device

Answer (score 0):

You can use a webservice which will takes in the ID as an arguments from the device. Deserialize the ID and run a query to database. Serialize the result to a json string and return to the device where you can use it...